# Get full tweet from node twitter

Tags: node.js, twitter, npm

I need to get full tweets from users and I'm using node twitter package. But it gives me only portion of the tweet.

eg:-

> text: 'I kind of hate how with most web development/new frameworks
>   etc., I start out with the intention “I’d like to spend…
>   (~link to tweet~)',   truncated: true,

Basically I need to turn off the truncation. Is it possible with this package or any other way to do this?

```
const express = require('express');
const Twitter = require('twitter');
const config  = require('./twitter');


var twitter = new Twitter(config); // initialize twitter

twitter.get('/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=donttrythis&count=2', function(error,tweets,response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log(tweets);
    }
})
```

I tried tweet_mode=extended also but not working.

Answer (score 2):

If the tweet is a RT, you get the full text is in `retweeted_status`.

```
var params = {screen_name: 'donttrythis', count: 10, tweet_mode: 'extended'};

twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return;
        }
    tweets.forEach(tweet => {
        if(tweet.retweeted_status) {tweet = tweet.retweeted_status;}
        console.log(tweet.full_text.trim());            
        });
    });
```